# Does filehelpers have classes which can support unlimited data record length?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, filehelpers

```
<FixedLengthRecord(FixedMode.AllowVariableLength)> 
Public Class FileRecord

    <FieldFixedLength(1)>
    <FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both), FieldOptional()>
    Public FileRecordsRemaining2 As String

End Class
```

I am doing a file import which can get uploaded txt file with data, and process the txt file then return back the file.

The code above is part of the FileRecord, which I will be getting and respond back the data record.

Question: Is it possible to use "FixedLengthRecord(FixedMode.AllowVariableLength)" where i can have "FieldFixedLength(**Unlimited**)"?

OR

Is there another way, another Filehelpers classes or something that can allow me to use to get and respond unlimited length of data record?

Answer (score 0):

The `FixedFieldLength` attribute requires a value greater than 1, but there is no upper limit, so you can just set it to `Integer.MaxValue`.

```
<FieldFixedLength(Integer.MaxValue)>
<FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both), FieldOptional()>
Public FileRecordsRemaining2 As String
```